# The method getInstance() is undefined for the type RandomGenerator error

Tags: java

I am new to Java and I was following of an example in online course. This lesson was dedicated to RandomGenerator. We wrote a small program that generates random number from (1,6). I wrote similar code to the example but I am getting errors.

Could you please point out what I did wrong?

```
import acm.program.*;
import acm.util.*;

public class RandomGenerator extends ConsoleProgram 
{
    public void run()
    {
        int dieRoll = rgen.nextInt(1,6); //The method nextInt(int, int) is //undefined for the type RandomGenerator
        println("You rolled " + dieRoll);
    }
        private RandomGenerator rgen = 
 RandomGenerator.getInstance();/*The method getInstance() is undefined for the type RandomGenerator*/
}
```

Comment: Where did you define a `getInstance` method?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Rename your class to something else other than `RandomGenerator` so you can use [`acm.util.RandomGenerator`](https://cs.stanford.edu/people/eroberts/jtf/javadoc/complete/acm/util/RandomGenerator.html)

Answer (score 1):

The name of `RandomGenerator` conflicts with the name of your class. You basically have two options, either use the fully qualified name

```
private acm.util.RandomGenerator rgen = acm.util.RandomGenerator.getInstance();
```

or - since this is kinda ugly - rename your class.